# Installing ADT into Eclipse-Juno. How to complete the installation after errors?

Tags: android, eclipse, installation, adt, eclipse-juno

I downloaded and installed `SDK Tools for Windows` (I'm using Windows 7 Professional - 64 bit and have Admin rights).

[Setting Up an Existing IDE](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html) page explicitly instructs:

> If you'll be using Eclipse, **do not** start the Android SDK Manager,
>   and instead move on to Installing the Eclipse Plugin.

I then followed [Installing the Eclipse Plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) instructions. I was able to download the plug-in (steps 1 - 7).  During installation I got the following errors:

```
Error: Missing platform-tools
[2014-01-20 20:26:59 - Android SDK] Error when loading the SDK:

Error: Missing platform-tools
[2014-01-20 20:27:18 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Error: Missing platform-tools
```

These tools were actually preselected and would've been installed by `SDK Manager`, but as (shown above) we were told **not** to do so.

What do I do now to complete the installation.  Do I install `Platforms tools` via `SDK Manager`? If so, do I unselect everything else?

I do not believe this case is covered in `Troubleshooting ADT Installation` section of the Android web-page.

Please point me into the right direction.

Comment: I installed a couple of weeks ago with no problems.  What step did you get to?

Comment: @user2310289 Up to step 7 then got errors shown in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

platform-tools used to be included in the SDK by default but for some reason Google removed it, and now you have to launch the SDK Manager first, and install the `Android SDK Platform Tools`.

You can go ahead and install other packages as well at this stage if you want, but all you have to install is the `platform-tools`. After that you can start eclipse again, go to `Window--> Preferences --> Android` and point it to the right location

Comment: I installed `Platform Tools` (had to run `SDK Manager` as Administrator`). Opened `Android` section and saw the right folder in `SDK Location` field.  The screen does not show any `SDK Tragets`, should it?  How can I **verify** the overall installation?

Comment: you just did. at this point you can go ahead and install the SDK targets using `Window--> Android SDK Manager` then select the newest build tools, and the Android versions you want to develop for. You might need to do this as administrator again

Comment: I want to say "Thank you" one more time.  I neglected to run `SDK Manager` as `Administrator` when installing targets and couldn't understand what was going on until I re-read your response.